# Browserify and Reactify source maps include full local path names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, watchify, reactify

I use watchify/ browserify to create a bundle with debug source maps with this command-

```
watchify main.js -o bundle.js -v -d
```

When I use Chrome DevTools to debug the resulting app, the source files are accessible in their orginal nested folder locations, visible in DevTools' **Sources** panel.

[image]

However when I run it through reactify with this command-

```
watchify main.js -t reactify -o bundle.js -v -d
```

Chrome DevTools shows all the source files in the same folder as `bundle.js` and the file name includes the full local path name.

[image]

I am finding this annoying and hard to identify the correct file both in the sources panel and in the individual tabs as the file is too long to display.

Does anyone know how to get around this so that the source files display in their original folder locations (as per pic 1). Thx

Comment: An update on this. I did use Dom's answer below and (I am sure) it worked for me at the time but now I am unable to repeat that success. In the end I used webpack and it does exactly what I want (plus more). There was a little bit of extra work in setting it up and getting it to work but it wasnt too much and I think it was worth it. This tutorial was very helpful in getting something up and running that I could build on for my own project- http://jslog.com/2014/10/02/react-with-webpack-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need specify the *--full-paths* option for browserify as **false**

See: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage

```
watchify main.js -t reactify -o bundle.js -v -d --full-paths=false
```

Comment: Would you mind posting and example of the command I would use to do this. I have tried numerous times and cannot get any different outcome. (The commands I am using are in the original question). Thanks

Comment: `watchify main.js -t reactify -o bundle.js -v -d --full-paths=false` ?

Comment: Thanks! You would not believe the number of times I tried this with and without other options, inside browserify options in package.json etc. etc. But I omitted the equals sign on the command line in `--full-paths=false` duh! (Not sure why browserify options in package.json didnt work as I did `"browserify": {
      "transform": [
        "reactify"
      ],
      "full-paths": false
  } `. Anyway, thanks a lot