# Browswerify compiling to full paths even when fullPaths is set to false

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, browserify, commonjs

I have the following gulp task:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    reactify = require('reactify'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify');

var sourcesDir = './react',
    appEntryPoint = "req.jsx",
    targetDir = './build';


gulp.task('default', function() {
  return browserify({entries: [sourcesDir + '/' + appEntryPoint], fullPaths:false, debug: true})
    .transform(reactify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(appEntryPoint))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetDir))
    .pipe(notify("Bundling done."));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(sourcesDir + '/' + "*.jsx", ['default']);
});
```

When I go to the build folder and see the built file. It contains full paths of some js files. How do prevent that?

Comment: I had a similar issue here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227862/browserify-and-reactify-source-maps-include-full-local-path-names . I never really resolved it but I suspect in my case it was because of reactify. I ended up switching to webpack.

Comment: @DavePile really? I spend the whole day to fix this!! So you're positive there's not solution for this now?

Comment: No I am not positive. There may be a solution but I dont know it :) I spent a similar amount of time. The reason I think it was reactify is because I set up a test project without jsx, only js files and when I pass them through reactify i get full paths in the chrome debugger, when I dont use reactify i dont get full paths. You can see this in my question. The answer I marked as correct, initially i thought it worked but when I came back it wasnt working so I am now unsure if i didnt test it properly or some other problem came up later. Anyway, I find a few extra benefits in webpack as well

Comment: @DavePile Great. I don't want to waste time on this. So you think I'll be okay with webpack? I'm new to these tools.

Comment: I was hesitant at first because there always seems to be some new tool you have to learn but it is pretty good. good luck